# Time (DateTime) Format Conditionally Show Minutes

Tags: c#, datetime, format

The jquery [FullCalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/) has a neat format for time.

If it the time is **7:00pm**, the format shows up as **7p**.

If it the time is **7:30am**, the format shows up as **7:30a**.

**Question:** Is there any way to use standard formatting to accomplish this with c# sharp? Obviously I can create logic to do this myself, but I'm hoping there is a format string that will accopmlish this.

ie (doesn't work):

```
MyDateTime.ToString("h{:mm}t");
```

Comment: No built in way to do it as far as I am aware...although you could perhaps make your own extension method for this purpose? i.e. ToShortHandString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting strings do not have conditionals - there is no way to specify a condition within a format string.

You will need to use a standard `if` and format accordingly.

```
if(MyDateTime.Minutes == 0)
{
  return MyDateTime.ToString("h");
}

return MyDateTime.ToString"h:mmt");
```

Or, in one line:

```
return MyDateTime.ToString((MyDateTime.Minutes == 0)?"h":"h:mmt");
```

Comment: I'd still be tempted to go with an extension method for this purpose though, keep it tidier if used throughout the project.

Comment: @KingCronus - Sure. I didn't say you can't make the above into one.

Comment: I wasn't correcting you, I was just leaving a note for the OP ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys. Btw I will be creating an extention method, just was hoping there was some way to do it in the framework with string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing like this within the built-in .NET date/time formatting. You'll have to write the code yourself.

(I haven't seen anything similar for dates and times in other date/time libraries, to be honest. I've seen conditional formatting for *periods*, but that's a different matter. The only exception to this is "fractional seconds" which can be expressed such that they're removed - including the decimal point - if the time is a whole number of seconds.)